# Transactional Sum at Daily or Monthly Intervals

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

In my collection, I have transactions logged.

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"5ae77296c780351beadc5518"
   },
   "payment_amount":10000,
   "store_id":{
      "$oid":"5aa6babce7c97f0875556ae6"
   },
   "operator_id":{
      "$oid":"5aa6ba95e7c97f0875556ae3"
   },
   "cashier_id":{
      "$oid":"5acd4144c94ba7250da4af78"
   },
   "player_id":{
      "$oid":"5ae75fccc780351beadc5493"
   },
   "payment_type":"deposit",
   "payment_time":{
      "$date":"2018-04-30T19:46:30.055+0000"
   },
   "__v":0
}
```

Now I need to aggregate the data in a certain way.

1. in last 12 month I need 12 results for each month. 
   in each result there should be sum of all `payment_amount` where `payment_type` is `deposit` and sum of all `payment_type == withdraw`
2. in last 31 days I need the same sums of deposit and withdraw but per day.

I am using mongoose and this is my schema

```
//schema definition
var Sch = new Schema({
    store_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    operator_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId, //users._id
    cashier_id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'usersMD'}, //users._id
    player_id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'playersMD'},
    payment_type: {type: String, enum: ['deposit', 'withdraw']},
    payment_amount: {type: Number, default: 0},
    payment_time: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
}, opts);
```

What would be the best way to approach this?

I was thinking to create two methods in log_transaction module in my API.

One would call for 1. and one would call for 2.

Comment: You can use $or for deposit and withdraw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm mostly going to talk about the "implementation" details here because there is a sound conclusion to how to can actually build methods around this once you have an understanding of how it actually gets done.

In an ideal situation you would actually be writing your data "pre-accumulated" for intervals such as the "month" or the "day" at the time of storing. That is generally how we do it in high volume environments, by writing accumulated totals as they occur.

Without that you are resorting to aggregation of your existing data, where the aggregation framework is what you should be using. Typically you would have at least some code for reporting different time intervals that you did not actually "pre-accumulate" for anyway.

The basic thing you are looking for here is the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator. This is a "ternary" or `if/then/else` condition which allows a condition to be expressed for `if` which branches the logic to return a value with either the condition is true as `then` or when false as `else`.

That is the operator which allows us to look at the `"payment_type"` and decide if the value has a "positive" or "negative" numerical representation when accumulating with [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/). So the basic statement here is:

```
 "$sum": {
   "$cond": {
     "if": { "$eq": [ "$payment_type", "deposit" ] },
     "then": "$payment_amount",
     "else": { "$subtract": [ 0, "$payment_amount" ] }
   }
 }
```

That applies the basic math here, so the rest of the task of accumulation is all about collecting "per time interval", and there are a number of different ways to do this:

## Monthly

#### Using MongoDB 3.6 [$dateFromParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/)

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "payment_time": { "$gte": start_date, "$lt": end_date }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "$dateFromParts": {
        "year": { "$year": "$payment_time" },
        "month": { "$month": "$payment_time" }
      }
    },
    "balance": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": { "$eq": [ "$payment_type", "deposit" ] },
          "then": "$payment_amount",
          "else": { "$subtract": [ 0, "$payment_amount" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

#### Using Date Math

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "payment_time": { "$gte": start_date, "$lt": end_date }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "$add": [
        { "$subtract": [
          { "$subtract": ["$payment_time", new Date(0)] },
          { "$mod": [
            { "$subtract": ["$payment_time", new Date(0)] },
            1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
          ]}
        ]},
        { "$multiply": [
          { "$subtract": [{ "$dayOfMonth": "$payment_time" }, 1] },
          -1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
        ]},
        new Date(0)
      ]
    },
    "balance": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": { "$eq": [ "$payment_type", "deposit" ] },
          "then": "$payment_amount",
          "else": { "$subtract": [ 0, "$payment_amount" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

#### Plain Date Operators

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "payment_time": { "$gte": start_date, "$lt": end_date }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "year": { "$year": "$payment_time" },
      "month": { "$month": "$payment_time" }
    },
    "balance": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": { "$eq": [ "$payment_type", "deposit" ] },
          "then": "$payment_amount",
          "else": { "$subtract": [ 0, "$payment_amount" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

The difference between the first two methods and the last being that those initial ones actually return the BSON Date object which will be represented under NodeJS as a standard JavaScript `Date` object. Both using [`$dateFromParts`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/) and the "Math" approach essentially returns a "rounded" date representing the first day of the month.

It is quite common for things like "bank statements" to actually issue on a "particular day of the month". This really only requires an extension of the logic presented to adjust, by simply "tinkering" with the day to return.

Say for the "15th" day of every month:

```
    "_id": {
      "$add": [
        { "$subtract": [
          { "$subtract": ["$payment_time", new Date(0)] },
          { "$mod": [
            { "$subtract": ["$payment_time", new Date(0)] },
            1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
          ]}
        ]},
        { "$multiply": [
          { "$subtract": [{ "$dayOfMonth": "$payment_time" }, 1] },
          -1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
        ]},
        1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * (15-1),       // n-1 days adjusting
        new Date(0)
      ]
    },
```

Which is a solid reason why I prefer the "Math" approach, since it's a lot more flexible than other forms. You can do it with those that rely on the other "date operators" but they end up applying "range conditions" on the day of the month in a way which takes a lot more logic to implement. Adding one additional number to an array however! What could be more easy than that?

Of course there is also things like [`$dateFromString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) and [`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfMonth/) as additional ways to do this with Modern MongoDB, however casting to "string" is an expensive operation. The more operations you have forcing something that is essentially numeric into a string form for manipulation ultimately has a cumulative effect which equals a big impact on performance. And in the modern world of paying for compute cycles and data transfer, that equals $$money$$. And I'm a *cheapskate*, so I like things to be efficient.

## Daily

Much the same as before with slight variation on how to get the "daily" intervals

#### MongoDB 3.6 [$dateFromParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/)

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "payment_time": { "$gte": start_date, "$lt": end_date }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "$dateFromParts": {
        "year": { "$year": "$payment_time" },
        "month": { "$month": "$payment_time" },
        "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$payment_time" }
      }
    },
    "balance": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": { "$eq": [ "$payment_type", "deposit" ] },
          "then": "$payment_amount",
          "else": { "$subtract": [ 0, "$payment_amount" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

#### Using Date Math

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "payment_time": { "$gte": start_date, "$lt": end_date }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "$add": [
        { "$subtract": [
          { "$subtract": ["$payment_time", new Date(0)] },
          { "$mod": [
            { "$subtract": ["$payment_time", new Date(0)] },
            1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
          ]}
        ]},
        new Date(0)
      ]
    },
    "balance": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": { "$eq": [ "$payment_type", "deposit" ] },
          "then": "$payment_amount",
          "else": { "$subtract": [ 0, "$payment_amount" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

#### Plain Date Operators

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "payment_time": { "$gte": start_date, "$lt": end_date }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "year": { "$year": "$payment_time" },
      "month": { "$month": "$payment_time" },
      "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$payment_time" }
    },
    "balance": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": { "$eq": [ "$payment_type", "deposit" ] },
          "then": "$payment_amount",
          "else": { "$subtract": [ 0, "$payment_amount" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Notably here the other approaches "added" a [`$dayOfMonth`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfMonth/) operator and the "Math" approach actually removed that same operator from it's consideration. The reason for this is because "months" are difficult to deal with in math operations, due to the basic fact that each month varies in the number of days it has. So what we are essentially doing in the "monthly" rounding is taking into account the present day in order to find the beginning of the month.

The point being here that the same "Math" presented actually applies to ANY time interval, be it days or years or hours or seconds. The ONLY time you need to vary and adjust is for accumulating a "month", which has an inconsistent number of days.

Also note the "repetition" here as everything is very much the same. At the most you should have two methods, but really the only part which need change is the accumulator between the month and any other interval, and particularly if you use the math approach. So honestly one method that identifies the difference between "monthly" and "everything else" is all you really should need, as aggregation pipelines are simply data structures anyway.

So "manipulate" them. Just like any other data structure.

---

> **NOTE** The question does not actually mention other than the "date" which field anything is meant to be accumulated for. Where you want something like per `"player_id"` then you simply add that to the `"_id"` of the `"$group"` stage as part of the compound key. A "compound key" is demonstrated on each **Plain Date Operators** section above.